# Python Json_Normalize : Need help flattening the data

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following JSON which I'm trying to flatten

```
[{
"id": "asdf1234",
"store": "Super78",
"fieldOpr":
[{"field": "stockType","operations": [{"equals": ["used", "wholesale", "auction"]}]},
 {"field": "price", "operations": [{"between": {"from": 1, "to": 1000000}}]},
 {"field": "status", "operations": [{"equals": ["In-stock"]}]},
 ]  
}]
```

My code up till now is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open(r"C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\testJsonFile.json") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
df = pd.json_normalize(data, meta = ['id','store'],record_path = ['fieldOperations']
                      )
df2 = df[["id","store","field","operations"]]
print(df2)
```

I'm getting the results in data-frame as

```
id :            store :          field:               operations:

asdf1234        Super78         stockType          [{"equals": ["used", "wholesale", "auction"]}]
asdf1234        Super78         price              [{"between": {"from": 1, "to": 1000000}}]
asdf1234        Super78         status             [{"equals": ["In-stock"]}]
```

I'm trying to get my DF to look like this after flattening.

```
id             store              field          operations    equalsValue   rangeFrom   rangeTo

asdf1234        Super78         stockType          equals        used          
asdf1234        Super78         stockType          equals       wholesale
asdf1234        Super78         stockType          equals        auction
asdf1234        Super78         price              between                     1          1000000
asdf1234        Super78         status             equals        In-stock
```

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are these the only operations that exist? Is it safe to assume that there will be only ona element in operations?

Comment: yes, equals and between are the only operations that exist. Only one element per operation.  Equals can be a single or set of comma separated values. Between will always have a - from & to range.

Comment: Hi @Bob203, if the answer below is helpful, could you accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to extract and transform.

Step 1. Extract

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, meta = ['id','store'],record_path = ['fieldOpr'])

df['operations'] = pd.json_normalize(df['operations'])
df['equalsValue'] = pd.json_normalize(df['operations'])['equals']
df['rangeFrom'] = pd.json_normalize(df['operations'])['between.from']
df['rangeTo'] = pd.json_normalize(df['operations'])['between.to']
```

Step 2. Transform.

Add a new `operation` column. This column is derived from the `equalsValue` column.

```
df['operation'] = df['equalsValue'].isnull()
```

Now you have `True/False` values in the operations column. Use that as a [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to assign a word `equals` or `between`.

```
df.loc[df['operation']==False, 'operation'] = 'equals'
df.loc[df['operation']==True, 'operation'] = 'between'
```

I almost forgot a step, so that's why it's last!

Explode the array of equals values so that each equals value is a row in the dataFrame. `df = df.explode('equalsValue')`

The result

```
    field        id    store equalsValue  rangeFrom    rangeTo operation
stockType  asdf1234  Super78        used        NaN        NaN    equals
stockType  asdf1234  Super78   wholesale        NaN        NaN    equals
stockType  asdf1234  Super78     auction        NaN        NaN    equals
    price  asdf1234  Super78         NaN        1.0  1000000.0   between
   status  asdf1234  Super78    In-stock        NaN        NaN    equals
```

Comment: If you want to drop the original operations json column, `df.drop('operations', axis=1, inplace=True`